# Удаление записей в таблице с внутренним ключом

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Residence](
  [ResidenceID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [ResidenceStartDate] [datetime] NULL,
  [ResidenceEndDate] [datetime] NULL,
  [PatientRef] [int] NULL,
  [VenueRef] [int] NULL,
  [UserRef] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
  [PreviousResidenceRef] [int] NULL,
  [FK_Residence_Residence] FOREIGN KEY([PreviousResidenceRef])       
REFERENCES [dbo].[Residence] ([ResidenceID])                               
GO
```

Нужно удалить записи где `ResidenceEndDate < 2017-01-07`

Запрос типа

```
DELETE FROM RESIDENCE
WHERE ResidenceEndDate < '2017-01-07';
```

генерирует ошибку

> Конфликт инструкции DELETE с ограничением SAME TABLE REFERENCE "FK_Residence_Residence". Конфликт произошел в базе данных "Db demo", таблица "dbo.Residence", column 'PreviousResidenceRef'. Выполнение данной инструкции было прервано.

Comment: А что делать с записями, которые сами больше указанной даты (т.е. под условие удаления не попадают) , но при этом ссылаются на какую нибудь удаляемую ?

Comment: @Mirdin Тогда я не понимаю зачем вы мне написали, что создать ограничение нельзя. Я же только уточнил у ТС что надо сделать с записями. Я не предлагал переделывать ключ или делать что то подобное. предлагаю почистить все комментарии, они к вопросу не относятся

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам сначала необходимо удалить все зависимые записи

```
DELETE FROM RESIDENCE
WHERE PreviousResidenceRef IN (select ResidenceID 
                      from Residence 
                      where ResidenceEndDate < '2017-01-07');
```

Но! При удалении, у этих зависимых записей появятся свои зависимые и **DELETE даст ошибку**.
По этому лучше обнулить поле, которое ссылается на другие записи

```
UPDATE RESIDENCE 
SET PreviousResidenceRef = null
WHERE PreviousResidenceRef IN (select ResidenceID 
                      from Residence 
                      where ResidenceEndDate < '2017-01-07');
```

Затем уже удалять нужные вам записи.

```
DELETE FROM RESIDENCE
WHERE ResidenceEndDate < '2017-01-07';
```

Comment: Да, согласен, без уточнений от ТС большего сделать нельзя. Комменты думаю можно удалять.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала присвоил все записям где ResidenceEndDate < '2017-07-01' NULL

```
UPDATE Residence
SET PreviousResidenceRef = NULL
WHERE ResidenceEndDate < '2017-07-01';
```

Далее использовал процедуру ALL

```
delete from Residence
where (ResidenceEndDate < '2017-01-07') AND
(ResidenceID != ALL(
    SELECT PreviousResidenceRef FROM Residence
    WHERE PreviousResidenceRef IS NOT NULL));
```